# Intersection of two generative neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, neural-computing

I have an input x (a word), and I have a neural network Y such that Y(x), which is an image always satisfies F(x), and another neural network Z such that Z(x), which is also an image, always satisfies G(x).  Is there any way to turn this into a neural network Q where Q(x), which is also a image, satisfies "F(x) ∧ G(x)"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general.  It's possible that $G(x)=\neg F(x)$, for instance.